# Putting the "canonical" working directory in a zsh prompt on OS X (iTerm 2, if that matters)

Tags: macos, command-line, shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I use zsh and oh-my-zsh for my shell environment on OS X, and I'm having a hard time tracking down whether or not the thing that is happening is a result of an oh-my-zsh function or the default behavior of zsh; it's entirely a cosmetic issue but it drives me crazy.

The short version is that if I `cd` in to a directory, the thing that is printed in my prompt from `%c` is *exactly* the argument that was passed in to `cd`; so if I'm changing in to the directory "test" but I spell it "tEst" by accident, then "tEst" is what will show up in my prompt.  This is very annoying.

Another example of where it pops up is when I use this shell function (simplified from [Brett Terpstra](http://brettterpstra.com/2013/02/09/quick-tip-jumping-to-the-finder-location-in-terminal/))

```
cdf()
 {
   target=`osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to get POSIX path of (target of front Finder window as text)'`
   cd ${target}
 }
```

When I use this function, regardless of what directory I end up in, my working directory is displayed as `~target` in my prompt.

Like I said, these are totally cosmetic issues, but it's driving me crazy.  Is this a zsh thing, an oh-my-zsh thing, or is there a different expansion I can use in my prompt settings that would fix this?  I'm using iTerm 2 but I've tried it in Terminal.app and the same thing happens.

Comment: Does it work better as %1~ instead of %c?

Comment: @BraddSzonye behaves the exact same.

Comment: Hm, what does `$PWD` look like when you `cd` into these directories? You might be able to use that instead of `%c` in your prompt, perhaps after some shell substitution processing.

Comment: @BraddSzonye `echo $PWD` spits out the same :-/

Comment: OK, that's just not right. I have an idea, let me do a little more research when I'm at my Unix box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two parts of your question have different resolutions.

## `cd TEst`

This behavior results from the interaction of two quirks:

- OS X uses a case-insensitive file system by default.
- Shells set `PWD` to the "current working directory as set by the `cd` command," as opposed to the absolute path reported by the `getcwd` system call.

The latter quirk allows you to use symlinks as if they were normal directories. By remembering the path you typed instead of the absolute path, the shell lets you `cd symlink` ... `cd ..` to get back to where you started. On a case-insensitive file system, typos like `cd TEst` behave just like symlinks, setting `PWD` to the path you typed instead of the directory's filesystem name.

To work around this, you can use `$(pwd -P)` to get the canonical path as reported by `getcwd` instead of the shell's logical path. Beware that this has the side effect of resolving all symlinks in the path. To mimic the formatting of `%c` use: `$(basename $(pwd -P | sed "s#$HOME#~#"))`

Alternately, you could convert your file system to case-sensitive, but some OS X applications like Steam and Photoshop are not compatible.

## `cd ${target}`

I cannot reproduce this behavior in OS X with plain `zsh` – it may be a problem with oh-my-zsh or your configuration. While you can use the same `$(pwd -P)` workaround for this, other scripts and programs may fail if `$PWD` does not resolve to a legitimate path. If you can reproduce the problem with a minimal oh-my-zsh installation, you should report a bug to the maintainers.

Comment: Regarding the whole `${target}` thing, this is *not* an issue if I use `PWD`, it's only an issue if I use things like `%c`.  But using `pwd` in my prompt shows the entire path instead of just the name of the current directory.  I sort of prefer the succinctness of `%c` but using `pwd` might be tolerable.

Comment: So, I ended up making a compromise; I'm not gonna worry so much about the case sensitivity stuff yet, but in order to fix the `${target}` thing, I've decided to use the following in my prompt: `$(basename \`pwd\` | sed 's/dstephen/\~/')`

Comment: Good solution. I will add the basename & sed parts to my answer, since it's a closer replacement to %c. If you don't care about `~` replacement, you can simplify that to: `${PWD##*/}`

Comment: Awesome.  I like the `~` replacement, and I left out the `-P` option because sometimes my symlinks don't have the same name as what they link (semantically nice name for an ugly directory) to and I prefer the symlinked names to be displayed in the prompt.